# xcode 4 can't re-add moved file

Tags: xcode, codesense

I had to move a file within my project folders.
After I moved it, xcode showed the file as missing (obviously).
So I re-added the file via drag-n-drop into the project and deleted the old entry in xcode.

Now the "new" file is still in xcode,
but for some reason for this filed code-sense and syntax highlighting is broken and if I try to build the project, xcode is complaining this file would be missing...

I already cleaned my project and also deleted the derived data, but it's still not working...
Any other ideas? Starting to go nuts over here :(

EDIT: Btw, tried with xcode 4.1 and iOS SDK 4.3 as well as xcode 4.2 with iOS SDK 5

Answer (score 0):

Ok strangely enough it worked after i added the file to another group than the one it was in before and as soon as i move the file back into the group it stops working again...
Deleting the group and recreating it worked.